# RSA implementation Help C++

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have to implement RSA Algorithm for about 50 different text files

But the problem where i stuck is that:-

RSA Algorithm generates an encrypted value for one character(ASCII) or for any number

But i need to encrypt different files having larger messages like

"My name is MARK, I must have to implement this RSA in any case..........

....

...

... large text upto 70-80 lines "

written in single text file

I googled my problem but didnt find any satisfactory answers for it..

If you know how can i do that that kindly help me with some link or something I need to implement this in any case ...

I am struggling on it with all my efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you typically generate a random number and use that as key to encrypt the file using a block cipher (like aes), then encrypt the key (a single number) with rsa.

for example, see [What is the limit to the amount of data that can be encrypted with RSA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583379/what-is-the-limit-to-the-amount-of-data-that-can-be-encrypted-with-rsa)

however, you can also use rsa to encrypt small sequences of characters by treating the entire sequence as a large binary number (for example, 4 8-bit characters as a single 32 bit integer).

don't forget to use padding when encrypting with rsa.