# Manually decrypt the signature in a digital certificate

Tags: c#, encryption, ssl-certificate, certificate, rsa

I've exported the root CA cert (ISRG Root X1) used by StackOverflow's digital certificate, as a DER encoded binary X.509 (.cer) file and used openssl in cmd to find out the modulus/exponent:

```
openssl.exe x509 -in C:\Cert.cer -inform der -text
```

[image]

I then did the same thing for the next certificate in the chain which is called R3, to get the signature:

[image]

Signature for R3:

[image]

I've copied these into C# as byte arrays and am using the following code to decrypt the signature:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace RsaDecryptor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] decryptedData;
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                var bytesRead = 0;
                
                // From ISRG root CA:
                var modulus = new byte[] { 0xad, 0xe8, 0x24, 0x73, 0xf4, 0x14, 0x37, 0xf3, 0x9b, 0x9e, 0x2b, 0x57, 0x28, 0x1c, 
                    0x87, 0xbe, 0xdc, 0xb7, 0xdf, 0x38, 0x90, 0x8c, 0x6e, 0x3c, 0xe6, 0x57, 0xa0, 0x78, 0xf7, 0x75, 0xc2, 0xa2, 
                    0xfe, 0xf5, 0x6a, 0x6e, 0xf6, 0x00, 0x4f, 0x28, 0xdb, 0xde, 0x68, 0x86, 0x6c, 0x44, 0x93, 0xb6, 0xb1, 0x63, 
                    0xfd, 0x14, 0x12, 0x6b, 0xbf, 0x1f, 0xd2, 0xea, 0x31, 0x9b, 0x21, 0x7e, 0xd1, 0x33, 0x3c, 0xba, 0x48, 0xf5, 
                    0xdd, 0x79, 0xdf, 0xb3, 0xb8, 0xff, 0x12, 0xf1, 0x21, 0x9a, 0x4b, 0xc1, 0x8a, 0x86, 0x71, 0x69, 0x4a, 0x66, 
                    0x66, 0x6c, 0x8f, 0x7e, 0x3c, 0x70, 0xbf, 0xad, 0x29, 0x22, 0x06, 0xf3, 0xe4, 0xc0, 0xe6, 0x80, 0xae, 0xe2, 
                    0x4b, 0x8f, 0xb7, 0x99, 0x7e, 0x94, 0x03, 0x9f, 0xd3, 0x47, 0x97, 0x7c, 0x99, 0x48, 0x23, 0x53, 0xe8, 0x38, 
                    0xae, 0x4f, 0x0a, 0x6f, 0x83, 0x2e, 0xd1, 0x49, 0x57, 0x8c, 0x80, 0x74, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x2f, 0xd0, 0x38, 0x8d, 
                    0x7b, 0x03, 0x70, 0x21, 0x1b, 0x75, 0xf2, 0x30, 0x3c, 0xfa, 0x8f, 0xae, 0xdd, 0xda, 0x63, 0xab, 0xeb, 0x16, 
                    0x4f, 0xc2, 0x8e, 0x11, 0x4b, 0x7e, 0xcf, 0x0b, 0xe8, 0xff, 0xb5, 0x77, 0x2e, 0xf4, 0xb2, 0x7b, 0x4a, 0xe0, 
                    0x4c, 0x12, 0x25, 0x0c, 0x70, 0x8d, 0x03, 0x29, 0xa0, 0xe1, 0x53, 0x24, 0xec, 0x13, 0xd9, 0xee, 0x19, 0xbf, 
                    0x10, 0xb3, 0x4a, 0x8c, 0x3f, 0x89, 0xa3, 0x61, 0x51, 0xde, 0xac, 0x87, 0x07, 0x94, 0xf4, 0x63, 0x71, 0xec, 
                    0x2e, 0xe2, 0x6f, 0x5b, 0x98, 0x81, 0xe1, 0x89, 0x5c, 0x34, 0x79, 0x6c, 0x76, 0xef, 0x3b, 0x90, 0x62, 0x79, 
                    0xe6, 0xdb, 0xa4, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x26, 0xc5, 0xd0, 0x10, 0xe1, 0x0e, 0xde, 0xd9, 0x10, 0x8e, 0x16, 0xfb, 0xb7, 
                    0xf7, 0xa8, 0xf7, 0xc7, 0xe5, 0x02, 0x07, 0x98, 0x8f, 0x36, 0x08, 0x95, 0xe7, 0xe2, 0x37, 0x96, 0x0d, 0x36, 
                    0x75, 0x9e, 0xfb, 0x0e, 0x72, 0xb1, 0x1d, 0x9b, 0xbc, 0x03, 0xf9, 0x49, 0x05, 0xd8, 0x81, 0xdd, 0x05, 0xb4, 
                    0x2a, 0xd6, 0x41, 0xe9, 0xac, 0x01, 0x76, 0x95, 0x0a, 0x0f, 0xd8, 0xdf, 0xd5, 0xbd, 0x12, 0x1f, 0x35, 0x2f, 
                    0x28, 0x17, 0x6c, 0xd2, 0x98, 0xc1, 0xa8, 0x09, 0x64, 0x77, 0x6e, 0x47, 0x37, 0xba, 0xce, 0xac, 0x59, 0x5e, 
                    0x68, 0x9d, 0x7f, 0x72, 0xd6, 0x89, 0xc5, 0x06, 0x41, 0x29, 0x3e, 0x59, 0x3e, 0xdd, 0x26, 0xf5, 0x24, 0xc9, 
                    0x11, 0xa7, 0x5a, 0xa3, 0x4c, 0x40, 0x1f, 0x46, 0xa1, 0x99, 0xb5, 0xa7, 0x3a, 0x51, 0x6e, 0x86, 0x3b, 0x9e, 
                    0x7d, 0x72, 0xa7, 0x12, 0x05, 0x78, 0x59, 0xed, 0x3e, 0x51, 0x78, 0x15, 0x0b, 0x03, 0x8f, 0x8d, 0xd0, 0x2f, 
                    0x05, 0xb2, 0x3e, 0x7b, 0x4a, 0x1c, 0x4b, 0x73, 0x05, 0x12, 0xfc, 0xc6, 0xea, 0xe0, 0x50, 0x13, 0x7c, 0x43, 
                    0x93, 0x74, 0xb3, 0xca, 0x74, 0xe7, 0x8e, 0x1f, 0x01, 0x08, 0xd0, 0x30, 0xd4, 0x5b, 0x71, 0x36, 0xb4, 0x07, 
                    0xba, 0xc1, 0x30, 0x30, 0x5c, 0x48, 0xb7, 0x82, 0x3b, 0x98, 0xa6, 0x7d, 0x60, 0x8a, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0x29, 0x82, 
                    0xcc, 0xba, 0xbd, 0x83, 0x04, 0x1b, 0xa2, 0x83, 0x03, 0x41, 0xa1, 0xd6, 0x05, 0xf1, 0x1b, 0xc2, 0xb6, 0xf0, 
                    0xa8, 0x7c, 0x86, 0x3b, 0x46, 0xa8, 0x48, 0x2a, 0x88, 0xdc, 0x76, 0x9a, 0x76, 0xbf, 0x1f, 0x6a, 0xa5, 0x3d, 
                    0x19, 0x8f, 0xeb, 0x38, 0xf3, 0x64, 0xde, 0xc8, 0x2b, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x28, 0xff, 0xf7, 0xdb, 0xe2, 0x15, 0x42, 
                    0xd4, 0x22, 0xd0, 0x27, 0x5d, 0xe1, 0x79, 0xfe, 0x18, 0xe7, 0x70, 0x88, 0xad, 0x4e, 0xe6, 0xd9, 0x8b, 0x3a, 
                    0xc6, 0xdd, 0x27, 0x51, 0x6e, 0xff, 0xbc, 0x64, 0xf5, 0x33, 0x43, 0x4f };

                // From R3 intermediate CA:
                var signature = new byte[] { 0x85, 0xca, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x3e, 0xa3, 0xf7, 0x85, 0x44, 0x85, 0xbc, 0xd5, 0x67, 0x78, 
                    0xb2, 0x98, 0x63, 0xad, 0x75, 0x4d, 0x1e, 0x96, 0x3d, 0x33, 0x65, 0x72, 0x54, 0x2d, 0x81, 0xa0, 0xea, 0xc3, 
                    0xed, 0xf8, 0x20, 0xbf, 0x5f, 0xcc, 0xb7, 0x70, 0x00, 0xb7, 0x6e, 0x3b, 0xf6, 0x5e, 0x94, 0xde, 0xe4, 0x20, 
                    0x9f, 0xa6, 0xef, 0x8b, 0xb2, 0x03, 0xe7, 0xa2, 0xb5, 0x16, 0x3c, 0x91, 0xce, 0xb4, 0xed, 0x39, 0x02, 0xe7, 
                    0x7c, 0x25, 0x8a, 0x47, 0xe6, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x3f, 0x46, 0xf4, 0xd9, 0xf0, 0xce, 0x94, 0x2b, 0xee, 0x54, 0xce, 
                    0x12, 0xbc, 0x8c, 0x27, 0x4b, 0xb8, 0xc1, 0x98, 0x2f, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0xcd, 0x71, 0x91, 0x4a, 0x08, 0xb7, 0xc8, 
                    0xb8, 0x23, 0x7b, 0x04, 0x2d, 0x08, 0xf9, 0x08, 0x57, 0x3e, 0x83, 0xd9, 0x04, 0x33, 0x0a, 0x47, 0x21, 0x78, 
                    0x09, 0x82, 0x27, 0xc3, 0x2a, 0xc8, 0x9b, 0xb9, 0xce, 0x5c, 0xf2, 0x64, 0xc8, 0xc0, 0xbe, 0x79, 0xc0, 0x4f, 
                    0x8e, 0x6d, 0x44, 0x0c, 0x5e, 0x92, 0xbb, 0x2e, 0xf7, 0x8b, 0x10, 0xe1, 0xe8, 0x1d, 0x44, 0x29, 0xdb, 0x59, 
                    0x20, 0xed, 0x63, 0xb9, 0x21, 0xf8, 0x12, 0x26, 0x94, 0x93, 0x57, 0xa0, 0x1d, 0x65, 0x04, 0xc1, 0x0a, 0x22, 
                    0xae, 0x10, 0x0d, 0x43, 0x97, 0xa1, 0x18, 0x1f, 0x7e, 0xe0, 0xe0, 0x86, 0x37, 0xb5, 0x5a, 0xb1, 0xbd, 0x30, 
                    0xbf, 0x87, 0x6e, 0x2b, 0x2a, 0xff, 0x21, 0x4e, 0x1b, 0x05, 0xc3, 0xf5, 0x18, 0x97, 0xf0, 0x5e, 0xac, 0xc3, 
                    0xa5, 0xb8, 0x6a, 0xf0, 0x2e, 0xbc, 0x3b, 0x33, 0xb9, 0xee, 0x4b, 0xde, 0xcc, 0xfc, 0xe4, 0xaf, 0x84, 0x0b, 
                    0x86, 0x3f, 0xc0, 0x55, 0x43, 0x36, 0xf6, 0x68, 0xe1, 0x36, 0x17, 0x6a, 0x8e, 0x99, 0xd1, 0xff, 0xa5, 0x40, 
                    0xa7, 0x34, 0xb7, 0xc0, 0xd0, 0x63, 0x39, 0x35, 0x39, 0x75, 0x6e, 0xf2, 0xba, 0x76, 0xc8, 0x93, 0x02, 0xe9, 
                    0xa9, 0x4b, 0x6c, 0x17, 0xce, 0x0c, 0x02, 0xd9, 0xbd, 0x81, 0xfb, 0x9f, 0xb7, 0x68, 0xd4, 0x06, 0x65, 0xb3, 
                    0x82, 0x3d, 0x77, 0x53, 0xf8, 0x8e, 0x79, 0x03, 0xad, 0x0a, 0x31, 0x07, 0x75, 0x2a, 0x43, 0xd8, 0x55, 0x97,
                    0x72, 0xc4, 0x29, 0x0e, 0xf7, 0xc4, 0x5d, 0x4e, 0xc8, 0xae, 0x46, 0x84, 0x30, 0xd7, 0xf2, 0x85, 0x5f, 0x18, 
                    0xa1, 0x79, 0xbb, 0xe7, 0x5e, 0x70, 0x8b, 0x07, 0xe1, 0x86, 0x93, 0xc3, 0xb9, 0x8f, 0xdc, 0x61, 0x71, 0x25, 
                    0x2a, 0xaf, 0xdf, 0xed, 0x25, 0x50, 0x52, 0x68, 0x8b, 0x92, 0xdc, 0xe5, 0xd6, 0xb5, 0xe3, 0xda, 0x7d, 0xd0, 
                    0x87, 0x6c, 0x84, 0x21, 0x31, 0xae, 0x82, 0xf5, 0xfb, 0xb9, 0xab, 0xc8, 0x89, 0x17, 0x3d, 0xe1, 0x4c, 0xe5, 
                    0x38, 0x0e, 0xf6, 0xbd, 0x2b, 0xbd, 0x96, 0x81, 0x14, 0xeb, 0xd5, 0xdb, 0x3d, 0x20, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x59, 0xd3, 
                    0xe2, 0xf8, 0x58, 0xf9, 0x5b, 0xb8, 0x48, 0xcd, 0xfe, 0x5c, 0x4f, 0x16, 0x29, 0xfe, 0x1e, 0x55, 0x23, 0xaf, 
                    0xc8, 0x11, 0xb0, 0x8d, 0xea, 0x7c, 0x93, 0x90, 0x17, 0x2f, 0xfd, 0xac, 0xa2, 0x09, 0x47, 0x46, 0x3f, 0xf0,
                    0xe9, 0xb0, 0xb7, 0xff, 0x28, 0x4d, 0x68, 0x32, 0xd6, 0x67, 0x5e, 0x1e, 0x69, 0xa3, 0x93, 0xb8, 0xf5, 0x9d, 
                    0x8b, 0x2f, 0x0b, 0xd2, 0x52, 0x43, 0xa6, 0x6f, 0x32, 0x57, 0x65, 0x4d, 0x32, 0x81, 0xdf, 0x38, 0x53, 0x85, 
                    0x5d, 0x7e, 0x5d, 0x66, 0x29, 0xea, 0xb8, 0xdd, 0xe4, 0x95, 0xb5, 0xcd, 0xb5, 0x56, 0x12, 0x42, 0xcd, 0xc4, 
                    0x4e, 0xc6, 0x25, 0x38, 0x44, 0x50, 0x6d, 0xec, 0xce, 0x00, 0x55, 0x18, 0xfe, 0xe9, 0x49, 0x64, 0xd4, 0x4e, 
                    0xca, 0x97, 0x9c, 0xb4, 0x5b, 0xc0, 0x73, 0xa8, 0xab, 0xb8, 0x47, 0xc2 };

                // The next line results in:
                // AsnContentException: The encoded length exceeds the maximum supported by this library (Int32.MaxValue).
                rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(modulus, out bytesRead);

                //var rsaParams = new RSAParameters();
                //rsaParams.Modulus = modulus;
                //rsaParams.Exponent = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x00, 0x01 };
                //rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);

                // If the 4 lines above are used instead, the following throws:
                // System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Cryptography_OAEPDecoding'
                // if fOAEP == true.
                // if fOAEP == false then it throws:
                // Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'Key does not exist.'
                var fOAEP = false;
                decryptedData = rsa.Decrypt(signature, fOAEP);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(modulus, out bytesRead);` is failing with:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'ASN1 corrupted data.'
AsnContentException: The encoded length exceeds the maximum supported by this library (Int32.MaxValue).
```

From the comments in the above code, you can see I'm trying another method, however this fails as well.

Is this the correct way to manually decrypt a signature using RSA?

Do I need to specify the exponent somewhere? Or is it assumed to be 65537?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? validate the signature?

Comment: @gusto2 yeah that's right. I want to verify the signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# does not support a low level verifying process, in particular no decryption with the public key is possible. However, this is supported by Bouncy Castle:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Encodings;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Math;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Encoders;
...
RsaKeyParameters rsaPublicKeyParameters = new RsaKeyParameters(false, new BigInteger(1, modulus), new BigInteger("65537"));
IAsymmetricBlockCipher rsa = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
rsa.Init(false, rsaPublicKeyParameters);
byte[] decrypted = rsa.ProcessBlock(signature, 0, signature.Length);
Console.WriteLine(Hex.ToHexString(decrypted));
```

This gives for your data (hex encoded):

```
3031300d060960864801650304020105000420444ebd67bb83f8807b3921e938ac9178b882bd50aadb11231f044cf5f08df7ce
```

The front part:

```
3031300d060960864801650304020105000420
```

identifies the digest, here SHA256. The rest is the actual hash of the signed data:

```
444ebd67bb83f8807b3921e938ac9178b882bd50aadb11231f044cf5f08df7ce
```

---

Details:

The public key contains the modulus as well as the public exponent (which is 65537 according to the screenshot). The [`ImportRSAPublicKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importrsapublickey?view=net-6.0) method expects a public key in PKCS#1 format, DER encoded. So the error message is caused because a wrong key is passed. Regarding the padding: `sha256WithRSAEncryption` implies PKCS#1 v1.5, not OAEP.

When verifying, the data is hashed as during signing, the DER encoding of the *DigestInfo* value is generated and padded. This data is compared to the data resulting from decrypting the signature with the public key. If both data are identical, the verification is successful, otherwise it is not. This is described in detail in RFC8017, section [8.2.2.  Signature Verification Operation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-8.2.2) for PKCS#1 v1.5.

.NET does not support decryption with the public key, so a low level implementation of this process with the built-in classes is not possible. Of course, the *overall* process, i.e. verification, is supported with various methods, e.g. [`RSA.VerifyData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.verifydata?view=net-6.0). This method requires the signed data in addition to the signature.

---

Edit:

To verify the signature of the user certificate with C#, user and root certificate must first be imported, e.g. using BouncyCastle. In the following, PEM encoded certificates are assumed for simplicity (DER encoding is also supported, however):

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
...

string userCertPem = @"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
                     ...
                     -----END CERTIFICATE-----";
string rootCertPem = @"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
                     ...
                     -----END CERTIFICATE-----";
                     
X509CertificateParser certificateParser = new X509CertificateParser();
X509Certificate userCert = certificateParser.ReadCertificate(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userCertPem)); 
X509Certificate rootCert = certificateParser.ReadCertificate(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rootCertPem));
```

BouncyCastle encapsulates verification in the `Verify()` method:

```cs
try
{
    userCert.Verify(rootCert.GetPublicKey());
    Console.WriteLine("verification succeeded");
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("verification failed");
}
```

With regard to the previously mentioned `VerifyData()` it may be noted that with `GetPublicKey()`, `GetSignature()` and `GetTbsCertificate()` the public key of the root certificate, as well as signature and signed data of the user certificate can be determined, so that alternatively the verification can be performed with `VerifyData()`.

Comment: "the DER encoding of the DigestInfo value is generated and padded" - When comparing the unencrypted signature and the hash of the certificate, do you need to take padding into consideration? How does the padding work for my example? I've tried reading the RFC documents but they're very confusing.

Comment: Do you know why I get this output which is different to yours?
`3031300d060960864801650304020105000420444ebd67bb83f8807b3921e938ac9178b882bd50aadb11231f044cf5f08df7ce`

Comment: @DavidKlempfner - The results differ because in my test I used the signature you originally posted and I didn't notice that you had modified the signature. I've updated the example to take your change into account.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner - The padding for RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 (PKCS#1 v1.5 variant when signing/verifying) is hex encoded `0001FF..FF00`, where as many `0xFF` are added until the signature has the length of the modulus, s. [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#page-46). You don't have to take the padding into account, because it is _automatically_ removed during decryption.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner - If you only need a _standard_ verification of the certificate (your comment under your question gives that impression), I can expand my answer accordingly.

Comment: I changed the signature to be from the R3 intermediate cert instead of the root CA cert, sorry I should have mentioned that in the question. What I'm trying to achieve is mimic whatever Chrome does to verify the signature. What is "standard" verification, is that what Chrome does? What other verification types are there?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner - It seems that the primary issue is not the decryption of the signature, but rather the verification of the signature, possibly even (with respect to the Chrome reference) the verification of the certificate (which also checks, for instance, whether the certificate is revoked, whether the certificate has expired, etc.), s. e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57755028/9014097). In the Edit-section of my answer you can find an example for the verification of the signature.

Comment: Do you know of any articles where the padding is explained? I've had a look and can't see anything that mentions the values `0001FF..FF00`.

Comment: @David Klempfner - Yes, RFC8017, and especially the link I already posted above: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#page-46. There you find in chapter 9.2 under step 5: EM = 0x00 || 0x01 || PS || 0x00 || T. Here, T is the DER encoding of the DigestInfo value and PS consists of so many 0xff values that the signature has the size of the key or modulus.

Comment: Thankyou. Do you know these checks actually happen? Is the code for it in Chrome itself or is it part of the Windows OS?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner - This is most likely implemented in the browser, but the OS is involved in the validation, e.g. via the certificate store. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28761249/9014097) gives an insight into such a more comprehensive verification using `X509Certifcate2.Verify()` and `X509Chain.Build()`.